# sampling univariate gausssian with specific mean and standard deviation using jax.random.normal

Tags: python, gaussian, jax

I'm trying to sample from a gaussian with specific standard deviation and mean, I know the [following function](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.random.normal.html#jax.random.normal) is sampling from a gaussian with zero mean and standard deviation equals to 1:

```
import jax
from jax import random

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
mu = 20
std = 4

x1 = jax.random.normal(key, (1000,))
```

And I can adjust the mean by doing: `x1 = x1 + mu`, but how can I adjust the standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your samples this way:

```python
x1 = mu + std * jax.random.normal(key, (1000,))
```

If you do this, the histogram of samples will follow the expected distribution:

```python
import jax
from jax import random
from jax.scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

key = random.PRNGKey(0)
mu = 20
std = 4

x1 = mu + std * jax.random.normal(key, (1000,))
plt.hist(x1, bins=50, density=True)

x = jnp.linspace(5, 35, 100)
y = norm.pdf(x, loc=mu, scale=std)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This

```
x1 = std * x1 + mu
```

will give you want you want

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but when I plot the histogram of ```x1``` it doesn't look right

Comment: @ValientProcess that is somewhat surprising as this is a fundamental property of Gaussian random variables. It could help if you added the histogram to your question and explained why it does not look right to you. Perhaps something else is going on